# How to set message size limit for actix websocket actorless?

Tags: rust, websocket, actix-web

I need some help. So, I'm trying to send a websocket message that is in the size of around hundreds of kbs. I am using actix web, with actorless websockets. The problem is once, the websocket message (being sent to the server) exceed some number of kb (I don't know how much), it gives an error saying the payload size is too large. I have seen github issues and pull requests intended to fix this issue with actix-web-actors here:

- https://github.com/actix/actix-web/issues/925
- https://github.com/actix/actix-web/pull/1920

But I can't seem to a find a way for setting the payload limit the actorless way. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

- I have tried google stack overflow for possible solutions.
- I have tried loooking at github pull requests and issues for possible solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean you are using [actix-ws](https://crates.io/crates/actix-ws) instead of [actix-web-actors](https://crates.io/crates/actix-web-actors), then it does not look like configuring the maximum frame size is supported.

Internally both use the groundwork from [`actix_http::ws`](https://docs.rs/actix-http/latest/actix_http/ws/index.html) of which the `Codec` controls the maximum frame size, however actix-ws always uses the default ([source](https://docs.rs/actix-ws/0.2.5/src/actix_ws/fut.rs.html)) and doesn't allow you to override it like actix-web-actors' [`WsResponseBuilder`](https://docs.rs/actix-web-actors/4.2.0/actix_web_actors/ws/struct.WsResponseBuilder.html) does.

Comment: Yes, I meant to say I was using actix-ws, instead of actix-web-actors. I see that's quite unfortunate to hear, since I was planning on using it on another project. Does anyone have any recommendations for other rust web frameworks that have better websocket support? Preferably something similar to actix-ws's websocket interface. I have been looking into warp, but I'm not really sure about it until I make a toy project. Thanks for the reply btw, you saved me a lot of stress.

Comment: Axum is probably the biggest competitor and their [websocket interface](https://docs.rs/axum/latest/axum/extract/ws/index.html) is somewhat similar to actix-ws's